# Android wear 2.0 supported devices?

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-gear

Can anyone tell me what are all the watches that support Android wear 2.0. Also I am wondering whether Samsung Gear s2 with tizen OS support android 2.0 or not?

Comment: Android Wear 2.0 is not shipping yet AFAIK. Tizen devices are not Android Wear devices.

Answer (score 0):

**Can anyone tell me what are all the watches that support Android wear: 2.0?**

According to [Android Wear site](https://www.android.com/wear/check/), these are the current watches that support Android Wear

- LG Watch Urbane 2nd Ed.LTE
- Casio Smart Outdoor Watch
- Fossil Q Founder
- TAG Heuer Connected
- Moto 360 for Women
- Huawei Watch
- ASUS Zenwatch 2
- LG Watch Urbane
- Moto 360
- Sony SmartWatch 3
- Moto 360 Sport

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the LG Watch Urbane 2nd Ed. LTE (unlocked) does support Android Wear 2